# ${webappRoot} inside form tags

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to inject webapproot value into spring form like this

```
<form:form action="${webappRoot}/user/create" commandName="createUsr" method="POST">
```

However this doesn't work. So for now this works instead :

```
<form:form action="/Manual/user/create" commandName="createUsr" method="POST">
```

My application name is Manual so it works in second case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`

Comment: I don't think I can use any `${variable}` from jsp that's why I'm looking for alternative solution

Comment: Why, is it an old server? JSP 2 allows expressions in this form, and pageContext is an implicit object.